# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [move_base/move_base]: can't locate node [move_base] in package [move_base]

Tags: slam, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I download the packages rbx1 and move_base in the same workplace( I do this following the book ros_by_example_hydro chapter eight ), then I want fire up a node named move_base from a launch file in the rbx1,but has an error,that's why

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200019/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bmove_base/move_base%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bmove_base%5D-in-package-%5Bmove_base%5D/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-12-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If `rosrun` cannot locate the `move_base` node in the `move_base` package, then it is likely that the built version of the `move_base` package is not on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

Make sure the `move_base` package is on the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` (an environment variable). If it still doesn't work, then please post your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xuao](https://answers.ros.org/users/24740/xuao/) on 2016-04-15**:
I have encountered same problem like this, the detail are in [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/231804/error-cannot-launch-node-of-type-message_to_tfmessage_to_tf-cant-locate-node-message_to_tf-in-package-message_to_tf/), and i have tried many methods but no use, could you help me solve it?